# How to dynamically change style on conditionally rendered element in Svelte

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

Testing out SvelteKit 1.0 with a basic todo app but I'm unable to make the text strikethrough conditionally. When the user clicks the checkbox on the left of the TodoItem the text should change style to become strikethrough. I logged out the values for completed and textDecoration whenever they change and so I'm fairly confident the data is being passed correctly, the style just isn't changing for some reason.

I tried following the example laid out in the docs [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/style-directive) as closely as possible but it's still not working. Here is the code

+page.svelte (Home)

```
<script lang="ts">
    import SearchBar from '$components/SearchBar.svelte';
    import TodoItem from '$components/TodoItem.svelte';

    let todos = [
        {
            id: 0,
            text: 'first task',
            completed: false
        }
    ];

    const addTodos = (taskText: string) => {
        if (!taskText) return;

        todos = [
            ...todos,
            {
                id: todos.length,
                text: taskText,
                completed: false
            }
        ];

        console.log(todos);
    };

    const checkTodo = (id: number) => {
        todos[id].completed = !todos[id].completed;
    };
</script>

<h1>to-do app</h1>
<SearchBar onAdd={(str) => addTodos(str)} />

{#each todos as todo}
    <TodoItem
        text={todo.text}
        bind:completed={todo.completed}
        onCheck={() => checkTodo(todo.id)}
        onDelete={() => console.log(`Delete ` + todo.id)}
    />
{/each}
```

TodoItem.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let text: string;
    export let onDelete: () => void;
    export let onCheck: () => void;
    export let completed: boolean;
    $: textDecoration = completed ? 'line-through' : 'none';

    //console log when value changes
    $: textDecoration, console.log(textDecoration);
    $: completed, console.log(completed);
</script>

{#if text}
    <div class="todoContainer">
        <input
            on:click={() => {
                onCheck();
            }}
            id={`todo-checkbox-` + text}
            type="checkbox"
        />
        <div style:textDecoration style:textAlign="left">
            {text}
        </div>
        <div on:click={onDelete} on:keypress={onDelete}>x</div>
    </div>
{/if}

<style>
    .todoContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dash instead of camelCase with the [style:directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-style-property) (an example seems to be missing in the docs and tutorial)

```
style:text-decoration={textDecoration}
```